# C6386 - Buffer overrun while writing to 'buffer' when using fread() function

Tags: c

"Warning C6386 Buffer overrun while writing to 'buffer':  the writable size is '*Param*(1)**Param*(2)' bytes, but '4294967295' bytes might be written."

I'm writing a code to calculate a postfix expression using a stack implemented using linked lists, and I'm reading the postfix expression from a local file in binary ( fopen(filename, "rb" ) into a buffer.
I get the above mentioned warning at this line of code:

```
fread(buffer, sizeof(char), fileLength, file);
```

But, I've used calloc to allocate exactly the amount of memory I'd need based on the length of the file like this:

```
fseek(file, 0, SEEK_END);
fileLength = ftell(file);

buffer = (char*)calloc(fileLength + 1, sizeof(char));
if (!buffer) {
    perror("Can't allocate memory!\n");
    return NULL;
}
```

I don't understand where it got the "*'4294967295' bytes might be written*". Anyone care enough to explain what might be the cause, I'm a student and I'm not that much experienced with C.

Here's the entire function block:

```
int CalculatePostfix(double* destination, char* fileName)
{
    FILE* file = NULL;
    int fileLength = 0;
    char* buffer = NULL;
    char* currentBuffer = NULL;
    int numBytes = 0;
    char operation = 0;
    double number = 0;
    int status = EXIT_SUCCESS;;
    StackElement head = { .number = 0, .next = NULL };

    file = fopen(fileName, "rb");
    if (!file) {
        perror("Can't open file!\n");
        return -1;
    }

    fseek(file, 0, SEEK_END);
    fileLength = ftell(file);

    buffer = (char*)calloc(fileLength + 1, sizeof(char));
    if (!buffer) {
        perror("Can't allocate memory!\n");
        return NULL;
    }

    rewind(file);
    fread(buffer, sizeof(char), fileLength, file);
    printf("|%s|\n", buffer);
    fclose(file);

    currentBuffer = buffer;
    while (strlen(currentBuffer) > 0) {
        status = sscanf(currentBuffer, " %lf %n", &number, &numBytes);

        if (status == 1) {
            Push(&head, number);
            currentBuffer += numBytes;
        }
        else {
            sscanf(currentBuffer, " %c %n", &operation, &numBytes);
            status = PerformOperation(&head, operation);

            if (status != EXIT_SUCCESS) {
                free(buffer);
                while (head.next != NULL) {
                    DeleteAfter(&head);
                }
                return -1;
            }
            currentBuffer += numBytes;
        }
    }

    free(buffer);
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: Please provide a sample input for which you see an unexpected behavior.

Comment: What is the size of the file? `long ftell()` is being assigned to `int fileLength`. And `calloc()` takes `size_t` arguments. So the warning is that the file size being passed around might be truncated. Try with `size_t fileLength = 0;`

Comment: `4294967295` is the largest `int`

Comment: If the file you are reading is large, you have some really inefficient stuff going on.

Comment: This is a sample file I'm using to calculate the postfix expression

Comment: "3 7 * 2 + 2 5 * 3 * 1 + +", so, not very long. But yes, I see the problem if the file is very large, it's gonna use up a lot of memory. 

I changed the variable type of fileLength to size_t and the warning disappeared. Honestly, I had no idea what size_t did until now ...

Comment: Apart from "using a lot of memory" if the size is larger than an `int` can hold, the incorrect amount of memory will be obtained. The `size_t` type can represent the size of any object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ftell returns a long integer, fread takes a size_t which, depending on implementation, often is an unsigned int. So if you happen to get -1L (which is the error return code from ftell) back from ftell you will end up vid a massive large unsigned int.

So to solve this, check return value of ftell and make sure it is not -1L, then when calling fread cast to size_t